# jQuery: AJAX umlauts & special characters are a mess

Tags: jquery, character-encoding

I've just created my first ajax function with jQuery which actually works, but unfortunately the character encoding (for characters like ä, ö, ü, ß, č, ć, å, ø) is a nightmare.

My files and my database are all UTF-8. I've tried a multitude of options in the ajax function and the PHP function, none of which were satisfactory.

This is my ajax

```
var dataString = {
 'name': name,
 'mail': mail
 // other stuff
}


    $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/post.php",
data: dataString,
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
cache: false,
success: function(html){
 // do stuff
}
```

I've tried it without contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" and I've tried to wrap the affected data in encodeURIComponent(), none of which worked.

When I use that AJAX with htmlentities() in my php, my umlauts look like this in plain text: 
UE Ã�, AE Ã�, OE Ã�, ue Ã¼, ae Ã¤, oe o

And like this in the database: 
UE Ãœ , AE Ã„, OE Ã–, ue Ã¼, ae Ã¤, oe o

If I don't use htmlentities() but mysql_real_escape_string() instead (or neither), they look good in plain text, but they look like this in the database:
AE Ã„, OE Ã–, UE Ãœ, ae Ã¤ oe Ã¶ ue Ã¼

I've been trying tons of options for hours now, but I can't find a solution that works. So far the only option I seem to have is having them look like a total mess in the database, but that would be very contraproductive if those data sets need to be edited.

Comment: Doesn’t your last observation suggest that the problem is probably with the database (and perhaps PHP) rather than with jQuery and AJAX?

Comment: I've tried changing my database encoding to latin1, but there was no difference

Answer (score 6):

> I've tried to wrap the affected data in encodeURIComponent()

Nah, if you're passing in a `{}` object, jQuery will take care of UTF-8 and URL-encoding it for you.

> When I use that AJAX with htmlentities() in my php, my umlauts look like this in plain text: UE Ã�, AE Ã�, OE Ã�, ue Ã¼, ae Ã¤, oe o

If you must use `htmlentities()`, you have to tell it your encoding is `UTF-8` in the optional `$charset` argument, else it will (stupidly) default to treating all your bytes as ISO-8859-1, and encode them to inappropriate entity references, one for each byte.

Better is to use `htmlspecialchars()` instead, as it does not attempt to apply unnecessary encoding to characters other than the few ASCII characters that really need it.

> And like this in the database: UE Ãœ , AE Ã„, OE Ã–, ue Ã¼, ae Ã¤, oe o

How are you determining that? Does the tool you are using to grab data out of the database know about Unicode? (If it's a dodgy PHP web admin interface, maybe not. PHP isn't great at Unicode.)

It is possible that you're storing proper UTF-8 bytes in the database, but in tables marked as having a Latin-1 collation. This will work, in as much as you'll get the same bytes out as you put in, but if MySQL doesn't know they're UTF-8 bytes then case-insensitive string comparisons outside the ASCII range won't work right, so looking for `Ä` won't match `ä`. That may or may not matter to you.

> If I don't use htmlentities() but mysql_real_escape_string() instead

Whoah, careful. HTML-escaping is for the output stage to the page. SQL-string-literal-escaping occurs when creating an SQL query. You need them both, but don't mix them up or attempt to do them at the same stage, or you'll have all sorts of weird escapes-gone-wrong and potential vulnerabilities.

Comment: When I use htmlspecialchars(), the characters look good on the site but like this in the database: Ã¼ (regardless if the db is UTF-8 or latin1). I use SQLyog to access the database, I don't have a webinterface like phpmyadmin. They also look messy when I use my custom built admin interface to edit them.

Comment: OK, SQLyog *claims* to support Unicode so hopefully it should be getting it right. If it's important to you to have the data look right in the admin interface, you need to use `CREATE TABLE ... CHARACTER SET utf8` to create your tables and call `mysql_set_charset('utf8')` from PHP before using the database connection.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the problem is occurring when inserting the data into the database. Are you using MySQL? After connecting to your database server issue the query :

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

This will tell the database server that the client connection wishes to send data in UTF-8 and to interpret it as such.

Also, when sending this data to the browser make sure to set the ContentType header

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

This will tell the browser to interpret the data as UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Try use this function instead of htmlentities

`htmlspecialchars()`

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a solution that works for me; I **removed** the            `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"` from my jQuery ajax, I only use `htmlentities($value, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');` for processing the data with SQL and my database is set to utf8 unicode.

The characters are displayed correctly and are stored as `&auml;` for ä and so on in the database.

Comment: Please don't store HTML-encoded data in the database! HTML-escaping is an output concern that should happen always and only at the page-output stage. It doesn't belong in the data access layer. If you put HTML-encoded data in the database you won't be able to do searches like `LIKE '%uml%'` (it won't be able to tell the difference between an encoded umlaut and the text “uml”), every `SUBSTRING` operation (including implicit trimming due to field length limits) risks breaking an entity reference and producing broken HTML, and it'll mess up any non-HTML use of the table data like sending mail.

Comment: Oh really? I didn't know that, but I'm a bad programmer in general ;)

When I remove the htmlentities() from my script, my special characters look like this in the database again: Ã¼ 

Oddly, when I send the data only through PHP (when deactivating javascript), they look fine in the database (ä). So the problem is most likely caused by the jQuery ajax.